# Wavelength absorbed by cornea but not by air

Tags: laser, wavelength, vision, infrared-radiation

I'm interested in mounting laser diodes on servos and using them to transmit data.  However, I'd rather not accidentally blind someone, even if they (say) stare for five minutes into the beam.  My understanding is that certain wavelengths of IR (like 2000nm or around 2600nm, as far as I can see from the charts) are almost entirely absorbed by the cornea, and are therefore much safer - they can't be focused into a tiny searing point on the retina, because they don't make it that far into the eye, so it's about as safe as pointing it at your hand.  However, looking at charts of the absorption spectra of the atmosphere, it looks like many (all?) of the "safe" intervals are also ones that get absorbed by the atmosphere.  It's kinda hard to compare the eye-absorption charts with the atmosphere-absorption charts; they're all different sizes and scales and tend to only have rough axis labeling.  So, the actual questions:

1. What wavelengths of light have very near 100% absorption by the human cornea (and/or aqueous humor), but are attenuated by no more than 50% across 100m of open air on a somewhat humid day?  (The lower the attenuation in air, the better, as long as it remains eye-safe.)
2. Bonus question: are there any comparatively cheap laser diodes (< $20) that emit in that frequency alone?

Comment: This is why there are laser safety standards such as ANSI Z. They provide the requirements at various wavelengths.